# Icon size for Newstand shelf in iPod?

Tags: ios, ios6, newsstand-kit

What is the correct icon size for Newsstand shelf in iPod? 
I tried google but not getting any exact answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All size for these kind of image can befound in the Apple iOS HIG, there is a section [Newsstand Icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW12).

> All Newsstand apps need to supply a Newsstand cover icon that represents the default cover art in the App Store. The long edge of this icon should measure at least 512 pixels (1024 pixels for high-resolution devices). Note that this icon is separate from the app icon that all iOS apps must provide.